# Defer mootools-more.js jquery.min.js

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

When I Defer mootools-more.js jquery.min.js in joomla i start to get errors from javascript.
Is there a way to add something to a javascript that after defer the script work normaly? 
I know there is a good extensions JCH_Optimizer, but i am Nginx user, and gzip_static is on. When i Turn on JCH_Optimizer  it will add for me unwonted ttfb because of gziping all the js/css files. With gzip_static on; i get way more faster server response time.

Comment: Why are you trying to defer Mootools and jQuery?

Comment: I resolve all the problems that was slowing down my website manualy just cant get rid of defer java script http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.ekavet.com/oa7eUnrr

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758204/stop-loading-automatic-scripts-in-joomla-2-5) and [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/performance/javascript-async-and-defer)

Comment: Its a 3rd party extensions that i dont want to use. I prefer to do it manualy. And how to defer javascript in joomla i do know:)

Comment: There is a way, however it requires a core hack, so I'm not even going to mention it.

Comment: Why not? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Core hacks are never recommended as it could cause potential issues with the way Joomla works and also may get overridden in a Joomla update.

Comment: Joomla is not get updates every day. If i get a faster page speed when i do it manually and have some problems after update i don't care to spend couple of hours to fix it after update.. Rather then 3rd party extension do it for me and increase ttfb with more php files that will be loaded.

Comment: Well the choice is up to you. See the first link I provided you with, which shows you how to do it. It's for J2.5 so the line number may be different

Comment: I think You didn't understand me. I do know how to make defer  jquery.min.js or any other. The point is after defer i got problems with some other scripts from 3rd party extensions. jch optimizer adds try{javascript} but it didn't help me

Comment: If it's a problem with JCH Optimizer, then you will need to contact the developer of this extension ;)

Comment: Its not a problem with jch optimizer. I want to avoid using it. And Make it manually. But i dont know how to make 3rd party extensions javascript to work after i make defer to lets just say jquery.min.js.

Comment: @Donatas I would suggest not deferring jquery or mootools. If you must, defer the 3rd party scripts that depend on them.

Comment: Tanks for advice's:) I left like it is and start to optimize server then:)

Answer (score 1):

My answer won't directly answer your question, but will address the concerns of many. The Google PageSpeed Insights is a good tool - however, it is too good, and it requires perfection, which is very seldom achieved on real websites. Case in point: YouTube.com has a score of 54 for desktop, and is failing on mobile. Amazon.com has a score of 50 on mobile and 60 on desktop. Twitter.com has a score of 60 for mobile, and 37 for desktop. We are talking about 3 super major websites here.

Google.com gets a score of a 100, but that is because it is returning a 503 error to the tool, and is asking for a verification code.

I'm not saying that one should completely ignore the score and the advices of Google PageSpeed Insights, but what I recommend is that people shouldn't take it extremely seriously. A score of 80 (even 70) is good, as score of 85 is wow. If you're at the point where you are breaking your website just to make sure you have a good score, then maybe you have gone too far...